# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process

Tags: docker, go

I want to compile my source project with a docker container like this, at first it worked but now it's getting an error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "go build -o main gitlab.org/repo/user-management/main": stat go build -o main gitlab.org/repo/user-management/main: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0022] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I use jenkins to use this command

```
stage('Compile Source') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker run -v $(pwd)/:/app -w /app --name "${containerName}" golang:1.17 go build -o main gitlab.org/repo/user-management/main'
      }
    }
```

Has anyone ever compile the source code via docker container?

thank you

Comment: You should look at the [standard Jenkins pipeline support for Docker](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), which can handle the creation for you; something like `docker.inside('golang:1.17') { sh 'go build ...' }`.  The error you're getting sounds like some sort of quoting problem where the entire `go build ...` command is being interpreted as a single argument, though that doesn't match the Jenkinsfile fragment you show.

Comment: but my pic wants to compile the source code with docker cli, which doesn't take up disk resources to download golang with jenkins

Comment: The `docker.inside()` form should be very similar to what you show, except that Jenkins adds many more `docker run` options to better simulate the standard build environment.  Both use the same `golang:1.17` Docker Hub image and both should require the same amount of disk space.

Comment: That's why my pic wants to compile the source code with docker container..., minimizing disk usage